# Unable to deploy artifact using python (with zip explosion)

Tags: python, http, request, put, artifactory

I would like to deploy artifacts using Python (with a zip file which is like a set of artifacts and the dir-structure should be preserved - according to the docs)
When I use the following docs nothing happens (no files created in the repo) but I get an OK response:

```
import httplib
import base64
import os

dir = "/home/user/"
file = "archive.zip"
localfilepath = dir + file
artifactory = "www.stg.com"
url = "/artifactory/some/repo/archive.zip"

f = open(localfilepath, 'r')
filedata = f.read()
f.close()

authheader =  "Basic %s" % base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % ("my-username", "my-password"))

conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(artifactory)
conn.request('PUT', url, filedata, {"Authorization": authheader, "X-Explode-Archive": "true"}) 
resp = conn.getresponse()
content = resp.read()
```

How could I make it work?

Comment: Do you see the request in the request.log or access.log in Artifactory logs?

Comment: I figured it out for you, the file needs to be uploaded in a streaming fashion. I will update my answer with example code.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Solved it!

I put up a local artifactory and played with it, curl and requests to figure out what was going wrong. The issue is that artifactory expects the file to be uploaded in a streaming fashion. Luckily, requests also handles that easily. Here is 
code I was able to get working with an artifactory instance.

```
import requests
import os

dir = "/home/user"
filename = "file.zip"
localfilepath = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dir, filename))

url = "http://localhost:8081/artifactory/simple/TestRepository/file.zip"
headers = {"X-Explode-Archive": "true"}
auth = ('admin', 'password')

with open(localfilepath, 'rb') as zip_file:
    files = {'file': (filename, zip_file, 'application/zip')}
    resp = requests.put(url, auth=auth, headers=headers, data=zip_file)

print(resp.status_code)
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, now I pass the file object and also set the content type, but it still does not work :(

Comment: Oh just noticed something else, try reading the file in as a binary, not just a string. So "rb" instead of "r". If that doesn't work possibly it's something to do with how HTTPConnection works and another library may work, like requests.

Comment: I ve tried reading the file as a binary but it did not work. I ve also tried uploading a single file this way (deploying but not as an archive) and it worked

Comment: Thank you for the code using request. This one neither works. The server answers with 200 but no file uploaded.

Comment: Did the above changes fix it for you?